# Unix-process pathname with special character (When path is parsed in as variable)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a problem that I am unable to solve. I understand when we try to acces a path name in Unix that contains special character we can simply use the escape character.

```
 /home/photos\ 2020 #equivalent to /home/photos 2020
```

However, I am dealing right now with shell script, and one of the step requires me to read all the folders in the current directory.

What I have found is that, when I loop through all the folders, any space would be treated as a new line. For example:

```
# Suppose we have have a variable $paths which contains all the path names of the current directory. Returned by ls -a

for path in $paths;do
   echo "$line"
done

# Ex: If one of the folder present is /home/photos 2020 and /home/2020 & 2021, instead of being output as a whole line the result will be  :

/home/photos
2020

/home/2020
&
2021
```

Because of this, it makes further opertions very different. I basically tried everything: I tried to use sed to add replace the space by "\ " with an escape character, I tried to quote the variable as "$path" which only made things worth by treating the entire content of "$path" as a whole.

The only temporary solution I can find is to write the content in a temporary file, and then read the file by using "cat" and "while read line". However, this isn't really ideal as I am creating files in the system

Is there is way to solve it? (Hopefull easy ones as I am obviously not an experienced user of Unix)

Thanks

Comment: I think your problem is right in here: `# Suppose we have have a variable $paths which contains all the path names of the current directory. Returned by ls -a`. What does `$paths` contain? How do you parse the results from `ls -a`? When you have to deal with files names with spaces, you need to handle quoting carefully at each step.

Comment: See also [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `while read line` isn't reliable either -- it would need to be `while IFS= read -r line` to work for all filenames except those with newlines, and that's not the set of all possible filenames (newlines are legal!). The NUL character is the only safe delimiter to use to store a list of arbitrary filenames, and you can't store those in a C string (which regular bash variables are).